# storing reaction times with event.getKeys while playing a sound with sounddevice

Tags: python, audio, keypress, response-time, python-sounddevice

I coded an experiment in which participants are presented with a series of visual stimuli (stim duration: 100ms, trial duration: 500ms). Simultaneously with the onset of the visual stimuli, there is a sound playing for 100 ms. 
Some of the visual stimuli are targets and participants should press spacebar when they detect the target. 
I want to know participants' reaction times to the target. So I store, using event.getKey, the global time when the spacebar was pressed. I store a global time to compare the time of the onset of the trial with the time when spacebar was pressed. I do that because my inter-trial interval is short and it can happen that participants will respond to the target during the following trial.

The code seem to  work when I comment out sd.play of the sound, but as soon as the sound is played, the reaction times seem off and it always stores it in the trial following the target trial (even though I know I pressed spacebar during target trial).

Did anyone encounter this problem before?

Below is the code for the procedure:

```
def response_check(key):
    """
    Checks if a key was pressed.
    Keyword arguments:
    key -- containing either a keypress and a time or nothing (list)

    return:
    time -- nan if not pressed or time of press if pressed
    """
    if len(key) == 0:
        pressed = 0
    elif 'space' in key[0]:
        pressed = 1
    if pressed == 1:
        time = key[0][1]
    elif pressed == 0:
        time = 'nan'

    return str(time), pressed


for t in range(n_trials): # n_trials is the total amount of trials
    show_target_crosses(pauses, t, trial_paradigm[t], hi_targets, low_targets) # show target 
    l_trial_start = globalClock.getTime()
    check4esc() # check for esc
    #set stimuli according to condition
    standing = visual.Rect(win=win, name='up_cross_hor', width=(dimentions[1]), 
        height=(dimentions[0]), ori=0, pos=(0, 0), lineWidth=1, 
        lineColor=colors[all_crosses[trial_paradigm[t]][t]], 
        lineColorSpace='rgb', fillColor=colors[all_crosses[trial_paradigm[t]][t]], 
        fillColorSpace='rgb', opacity=1, depth=0.0, interpolate=True)
    laying = visual.Rect(win=win, name='up_cross_hor', width=(dimentions[0]), 
        height=(dimentions[1]), ori=0, pos=(0, position[all_crosses[trial_paradigm[t]][t]]), lineWidth=1, 
        lineColor=colors[all_crosses[trial_paradigm[t]][t]], 
        lineColorSpace='rgb', fillColor=colors[all_crosses[trial_paradigm[t]][t]], 
        fillColorSpace='rgb', opacity=1, depth=0.0, interpolate=True)

    sd.play(all_sounds[all_paradigms[trial_paradigm[t]][t]], fs) # Play sound 
    if first_seven[t] == 0:
        if all_responses[trial_paradigm[t]][t] == 0:
            trigger(trig_list[trial_paradigm[t]][all_paradigms[trial_paradigm[t]][t]],0.01) # send sound trigger    
        elif all_responses[trial_paradigm[t]][t] == 1: 
            trigger(trig_list_targets[trial_paradigm[t]][all_paradigms[trial_paradigm[t]][t]],0.01)
    core.wait(0.06) # adjust diode to sound delay
    standing.draw() # vertical bar
    laying.draw() # horizontal bar
    whiteOn.draw() # square

    win.flip() # show cross and white square for fotodiode

    core.wait(0.1) # show cross 100 ms
    win.flip() # turn visual stuff off
    core.wait(0.032) # adjust ITI

    l_fp = int(ok_data[0])
    l_block_nr = blocks[t]+1
    l_trial_nr = (range(367)*n_blocks)[t]+1
    l_condition = trial_paradigm[t]
    l_sound = all_sounds_names[all_paradigms[trial_paradigm[t]][t]]
    if first_seven[t] == 0:
        if all_responses[trial_paradigm[t]][t] == 0:
            l_trigger = trig_list[trial_paradigm[t]][all_paradigms[trial_paradigm[t]][t]] # send sound trigger    
        elif all_responses[trial_paradigm[t]][t] == 1: 
            l_trigger = trig_list_targets[trial_paradigm[t]][all_paradigms[trial_paradigm[t]][t]]

    elif first_seven[t] == 1: 
        l_trigger = 999
    l_target = all_responses[trial_paradigm[t]][t]
    l_cross_condition = all_crosses[trial_paradigm[t]][t]

    key = event.getKeys(keyList = ['space'], timeStamped = globalClock)

    l_response_time = response_check(key)[0]
    # Save data to file
    #'fp\tblock_nr\ttrial_nr\tcondition\tsound\ttrigger\ttarget\tcross_cond\ttrial_start\tresponse_time\n'
    dataFile.write('%i\t%i\t%i\t%i\t%s\t%i\t%i\t%i\t%f\t%s\n' %(
        l_fp, l_block_nr, l_trial_nr, l_condition, l_sound, l_trigger, 
        l_target, l_cross_condition, l_trial_start, l_response_time))
    paus(t, pauses, blocks, trig = 192) # check for pauses
```

=========== EDIT ============
Below I paste the MCVE version of the whole experiment:

```
from psychopy import visual
from psychopy import core, gui, data, event, parallel
import sounddevice as sd
import time, random, math, sys
import numpy as np

# Functions --------------------------------------------------------------------

def response_check(key):
    """
    Checks if a key was pressed.
    Keyword arguments:
    key -- containing either a keypress and a time or nothing (list)

    return:
    time -- nan if not pressed or time of press if pressed
    """
    if len(key) == 0:
        pressed = 0
    elif 'space' in key[0]:
        pressed = 1
    if pressed == 1:
        time = key[0][1]
    elif pressed == 0:
        time = 'nan'

    return str(time), pressed

def create_sinusoid (freq = 1000, phase = 0, fs = 48000, dur = 1):
    '''Create a sinusoid of specified length with amplitude -1 to 1. Use
    set_gain() and fade() to set amplitude and fade-in-out.

    Keyword arguments:
    frequency -- frequency in Hz (float)
    phase -- phase in radians (float)
    fs -- sampling frequency (int)
    duration -- duration of signal in seconds (float). 

    Return:
    sinusoid -- monosignal of sinusoid (1xn numpy array)
    '''    
    t = np.arange(0, dur, 1.0/fs) # Time vector
    sinusoid = np.sin(phase + 2*np.pi* freq * t) # Sinusoid (mono signal)
    return sinusoid

def fade(monosignal,samples):
    '''Apply a raised cosine to the start and end of a mono signal.

    Keyword arguments:
    monosignal -- vector (1xn numpy array).
    samples -- number of samples of the fade (integer). Make sure that: 
    2*samples < len(monosignal)

    Return:
    out -- faded monosignal (1xn numpy array)
    ''' 
    ramps = 0.5*(1-np.cos(2*np.pi*(np.arange(2*samples))/(2*samples-1)))
    fadein = ramps[0:samples]
    fadeout = ramps[samples:len(ramps)+1]
    plateu = np.ones(len(monosignal)-2*samples)
    weight = np.concatenate((fadein,plateu,fadeout))
    out = weight*monosignal
    return out 

def set_gain(mono, gaindb):
    ''' Set gain of mono signal, to get dB(rms) to specified gaindb 

    Keyword arguments:
    mono -- vector (numpy array).
    gaindb -- gain of mono in dB re max = 0 dB (float).

    Return:
    gained -- monosignal (numpy array)
    '''
    rms = np.sqrt(np.mean(mono**2))
    adjust = gaindb - 20 * np.log10(rms)
    gained = 10**(adjust/20.0) * mono # don't forget to make 20 a float (20.0)

    # Print warning if overload, that is, if any abs(sample-value) > 1
    if (np.max(np.abs(gained)) > 1):
        message1 = "WARNING: set_gain() generated overloaded signal!"
        message2 = "max(abs(signal)) = " + str(np.max(np.abs(gained))) 
        message3 = ("number of samples >1 = " + 
                    str(np.sum(1 * (np.abs(gained) > 1))))
        print message1
        print message2
        print message3

    return gained

# Screen
win = visual.Window([800, 600], allowGUI = False, # [1920, 1080]
    monitor = 'testMonitor', units = 'height', color = 'gray')

# ==============================================================================
# TONE ORDER AND  RESPONSES ----------------------------------------------------
# 1 - 500 Hz 
# 0 - 550 Hz 
# 2 - 605 Hz
# 3 - 666 Hz
# 4 - 732 Hz
# 5 - 805 Hz
# 6 - 886 Hz
# 7 - 974 Hz

tone_order =  np.random.choice([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 20, replace = True)
targets = np.random.choice([1,0,0,0,0]*4, 20, replace = False)

# ==============================================================================
# CREATE SOUNDS ----------------------------------------------------------------

#sd.default.device = "ASIO Fireface USB"
print 'Sound device ------------------------------------------------------------'
print sd.query_devices()#device = "ASIO Fireface USB")
print '-------------------------------------------------------------------------'

# Set the gain and sampling frequency (fs)
gain = -30
fs = 44100

frequencies = [500, 550, 605, 666, 732, 805, 886, 974]
tones       = [0]*8

for t in range(len(frequencies)):
    tones[t] = set_gain(fade(create_sinusoid(
        freq = frequencies[t], phase = 0, fs = fs, dur = 0.1),441),gain) # 100 ms, 10 ms fade in/out

f_500 = np.transpose(np.array([tones[0],tones[0]])) # deviant, control
f_550 = np.transpose(np.array([tones[1],tones[1]])) # standard
f_605 = np.transpose(np.array([tones[2],tones[2]]))
f_666 = np.transpose(np.array([tones[3],tones[3]]))
f_732 = np.transpose(np.array([tones[4],tones[4]]))
f_805 = np.transpose(np.array([tones[5],tones[5]]))
f_886 = np.transpose(np.array([tones[6],tones[6]]))
f_974 = np.transpose(np.array([tones[7],tones[7]]))

all_tones = [f_500, f_550, f_605, f_666, f_732, f_805, f_886, f_974]

# ==============================================================================
# CREATE VISUALS ---------------------------------------------------------------
stimulus = visual.TextStim(
    win, color = 'white', height = 0.03, pos = (0, 0), text = '')

# ==============================================================================
# Make a text file to save data ------------------------------------------------
fileName = 'test'
dataFile = open(fileName+'.txt', 'w')
dataFile.write('soundCond\ttarget\ttrial_start\tresponse_time\n')

# ==============================================================================
# Keep track of time -----------------------------------------------------------
globalClock = core.Clock()
respClock = core.Clock()

# ==============================================================================
# Experimental procedure -------------------------------------------------------

# Trial loop
for t in range(len(tone_order)): 
    l_trial_start = globalClock.getTime()
    #set stimuli according to condition
    if targets[t] == 0:
        stimulus.text = '+'
    else:
        stimulus.text = 'o'
    sd.play(all_tones[tone_order[t]], fs) # Play sound for current trial

    core.wait(0.08) # adjust visual to sound delay
    stimulus.draw() # vertical bar
    win.flip() # show cross and white
    core.wait(0.1) # show cross 100 ms
    win.flip() # turn visual stuff off
    core.wait(0.26) # adjust ITI

    l_sound = tone_order[t]
    l_target = targets[t]

    key = event.getKeys(keyList = ['space'], timeStamped = globalClock)

    l_response_time = response_check(key)[0]
    # Save data to file
    #'soundCond\ttarget\ttrial_start\tresponse_time\n'
    dataFile.write('%i\t%i\t%f\t%s\n' %(
        l_sound, l_target, l_trial_start, l_response_time))

dataFile.close()
```

Comment: If you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I can try it and probably give a better answer. I would not recommend to use `sd.play()` for timing-critical situations! You should create an `sd.OutputStream` and either use the blocking [write()](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.10/#sounddevice.Stream.write) method, or (maybe even better) a custom callback function where you can specify the exact time when the sound is supposed to be played.

Comment: Hi! thanks for a quick response! Me and my colleague were trying to figure out sd.OutputStream today and as a practice we wanted to replicate an example from this issue: [link](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/issues/98) . We cannot get it to work, instead we get an error: " dtype mismatch: 'float64' vs 'float32' ". Do you have any good, simple example how to use this function? Our program is extremely simple, we just want to play single sounds in a pseudo-random order.

Comment: The error means that a NumPy array with data type `'float32'` is expected but you are using `'float64'`. You can convert it with `myarray.astype('float32')`.

Comment: I don't have an example with the `.write()` method, because I never use it. Some of the official examples show how to use a callback function: https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/tree/master/examples/.

Answer (score 0):

Your second code example shows that you are using PsychoPy.
Why are you not using its audio capabilities?

Incidentally, the `sounddevice` module can be used as audio backend in PsychoPy and they are using an `sd.OutputStream` and a callback function internally, just as I suggested.
But if you use PsychoPy's audio functions, you don't really have to worry about that.

BTW, the PsychoPy community is really helpful, check out their forum: https://discourse.psychopy.org/.

Regarding this comment:

> Our program is extremely simple

Playing audio with exact timing is never simple.
There are big platform-dependent differences and you should always measure if you want to make sure the timing is right.